# Function uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Can I say that there is a constant $C$ such that

$\displaystyle\sup_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} (f(y)-f(x)-C|x-y|)<\infty$ ?

Comment: No. Consider, e.g., the $\arctan$ function.

Comment: And in $\mathbb{R}^N$ ?

Comment: $f(x_1,\ldots,x_N) = \arctan(x_1)$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. I was studying , and in the book is written "note that f uniformly continuous implies that there is a constant C such that ..." and so I did not understand.

Answer (score 1):

No: take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, yet for any $C> 0$ we have, taking $y=4x$,
$$
\lvert f(x) - f(y) - C\lvert x-y\rvert \lvert =
\lvert \sqrt{\lvert x\rvert} + 3C\lvert x\rvert \lvert =
3Cx + o(x) \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \infty
$$

Comment: Anyway if my constant $C=\rho(1)$ with $\rho$ the modulus of continuity of $f$ my thesis is true beacuse $\rho(r)\leq\rho(\delta)+(\rho(\delta)/\delta)r$ with $r\geq 0$, $\delta>0$ holds. $\rho(r)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)| : x,y\in\mathbb{R]^N , |x-y|\lleq r\}$

Comment: What do you mean? (also, your comment does not display correctly). Are you assuming something more on $f$? If not, how does that fare with the counterexample above? @L.G.A.G.

Comment: $\rho(r)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)| : x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N, |x-y|\leq r\}$. If $\delta=1$ e $r=|x-y|$ I have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \rho(|x-y|)\leq C+ C|x-y|$ with $C=\rho(1)$ and so $|f(x)-f(y)|-C|x-y|\leq C$.

Comment: Hmm... I have to think about it, but basically (eyeballing what you wrote) this would come from dropping the absolute values in my answer? (the counterexample given, without them, goes to $-\infty$).

Comment: I think yes. But anyway I wait your opinion. Thank you

Comment: After looking: doesn't the above rely on the fact the you assume the modulus of continuity to be concave (what you write in *"my thesis is true because [...]"*).  Why is that true in general?

Comment: I've read that for a function between metric spaces, it is equivalent to admit a modulus of continuity that is either concave, or subadditive, or uniformly continuous, or sublinear. So I think that $\rho$ is the concave majorant of "real" modulus of continuty. In that case that inequality it's true. What do you think about it?

Comment: I don't know that result... if it's true, then your proof looks correct to me, but you may want to check that point (e.e., by checking where you reads that.)

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks !

Comment: You're welcome... hope I could have had been more helpful.